# distinct mail and web hosting servers with multiple domains; spam-avoidance, PTR and SPF records

Tags: email, postfix, spam, reverse-dns

Context.

I have multiple domains web services being hosted on a Digital Ocean droplet (Ubuntu and Nginx in stack).  Apparently, DO automatically sets up a PTR record. However, when I query

```
host <IP_ADDRESS>
[...] not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

The droplet is using postfix, configured as  where `inet_interfaces = all inet_protocols=ipv4`, while `mydestination` includes the hosted web services domains (both with and without www prefix).  These domains issue e-mails via `sendmail` and a host defined as `scheduler.sending.ws`

DNS and mail service is run through a second provider (which is NOT the registrar of record for the second level domain). I noticed first of all that an A record is pointing to the proper ip address but with a typo `schedule.sending.ws` That can be fixed, although I am not certain this is entirely pertinent.

The MX record properly points to the second provider `mail.sending.ws` 
There are also two TXT records for `@` and `admin` pointing to 
`v=spf1 a mx ptr include:someserver.net ~all`.

This leads to mails being generated with the following header with a **random** domain defined in `mydestination` of the postfix main.cf file:

```
Received: from www.other.ws ([IP_ADDRESS]:46818)
```

Thus, two different issuing references, a situation which can easily lead to be flagged as spam.

*please excuse my utter confusion and the breaking protocol of asking multiple questions*
My present assumption is that:
a) does a new TXT DNS entry need to be set for the issuing domain, such as: `v=spf1 a mx include:scheduler.sending.ws include:someserver.net ~all` ?
b) if a) is correct, naturally the A record needs to be corrected
c) the mismatch in the headers still needs to be resolved.  But this must certainly be specified by the application (and thus specific domain) preparing the e-mail with one of the postfix-defined domains...  will postfix play along?

is any data missing to properly address this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For the overall situation, you should really follow some tutorials to make a working basic setup instead of trying random configurations with inadequate understanding on how email works. After all, administering an email system is complicated, challenging task this day. For anybody without strong experience and special needs for own email server it's recommended to use an external service that has all the required spam prevention systems and sender reputation handling out-of-box.

To answer your separated questions and to give guidance to learn the technologies behind. In this answer, let's use `www.example.com. A 192.0.2.1` as the web server and `mail.example.com. A 192.0.2.2` as the mail server for incoming mail. Both needs to send mail, but only `mail.example.com` receives it, right?

- a) No. The SPF [`include` mechanism](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#include) is not for that purpose. `include:scheduler.example.com` means that there are more rules i.e. other SPF record in `scheduler.example.com. TXT`. As there's probably no such record, it would cause a PermError, possibly resulting rejecting of the message.

  The SPF record should allow all the servers that will send mail for the corresponding hostname. If you use `example.com`, you have it on `example.com. TXT`, for `www.example.com.` on `www.example.com. TXT`. It's recommended to use the [`ip4`](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#ip4) and [`ip6`](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#ip6) mechanisms whenever possible, as it requires less DNS queries when checking for SPF. This would result in:

  ```
  example.com.      IN TXT  "v=spf1 ip4:192.0.2.1 ip4:192.0.2.2 ~all"
  www.example.com.  IN TXT  "v=spf1 ip4:192.0.2.1 ip4:192.0.2.2 ~all"
  ```
- b) For incoming mail delivery, `scheduler.example.com. A` is irrelevant unless it was used as a *mail exchanger* e.g. `example.com. MX scheduler.example.com.`, but probably there's only `mail.example.com.` if you use it as a `HELO` hostname, you should have the `A` record to avoid [SMTP banner mismatch](https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/smtp/smtp-banner-check).
- c) The `HELO` hostname matches Postfix configuration parameter [`smtpd_banner`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_banner). By default, it has the [`myhostname`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#myhostname) as a variable i.e. is the same you have as `myhostname`. The `mydestination` has nothing to do with this, and nothing chooses a random hostname from that setting: it's for delivering mail, not for sending it.

  The `HELO` hostname is required to have a matching `A` record and recommended to be the same as the `PTR` for the IP address. It doesn't need to match the *envelope sender* domain nor the `From:` header address. In a multi-domain email server that would be impossible, too.

For mail domain healthy issues, it's recommended to use actual domain so that we could check what's going on. This question is wide and unspecified: it's impossible to give accurate or general answer.

Comment: agreed that this is a complex issue & your points are enlightening. The incoming and outgoing mail server is outsourced to an external service. Point a) well clarified.  Point b), yes the MX record is only `mail.example.com`, thus that issue is put to bed. Point c) then I guess my proper goal is to dynamically associate the sending site with a `myhostname`.